# Merge 2 png blob in javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, png, blob

I have 2 screenshots created like this:

```
function takeScreenshot(dataObj) {
    html2canvas($('body'),{
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
                dataObj["screenshot"] = blob;

            }, 'image/png', 1);
        }
    });
}
```

What I want to do is to merge both of them, so I have one picture. I know I can do it by placing both pictures on the same canvas and then serializing it back to the blob. But I don't have to display it on the page, so it seems to me like an overhead.

Is there other, more optimized way, to merge this 2 blob into one picture?

Comment: What do you mean by "But I don't have to display it on the page" if you mean you don't want to display the canvas then your problem is easily solved as you don't have to add an element to the DOM to use it To create a canvas `canvas = document.createElement("canvas")`

Comment: There might be ways by inflating the pngs' image data, shifting all of one to the new position, and then rebuild the headers approprietaly, but if all you want is optimization, then go with the canvas way. If you really try to overcome an issue like max size of canvas, then you would be better go with a server side solution.

Comment: @Blindman67 yes, solution you've described works, but I am wondering if there more optimized way to do it

Comment: @unresolved_external No,not without vendor specific APIs and Privileged access (Eg extensions)  The problem is the image decoder, Javascript can not keep up with the native built in decoders, once the image is decoded a canvas is just a handy pixel buffer and does not carry much overhead on top of the buffer (if you keep the state clean)